# HIghcharts column graph with more than 50 data points

Tags: highcharts, column-chart

I am using Highcharts to render a **column graph with drilldown** with the following options:

```
chart: {
  type: 'column',
  inverted: true,
},
xAxis: {
  type: 'category', max: 5,
},
yAxis: {
  title: { text: '' },
  labels: {
    enabled: false
  },
},
```

My Series contains more than 50 data points. When I try to scroll down, it shows index numbers instead of x-Axis labels. It starts to misbehave as and when the number of data points exceeds the count of 50.

But 'columnrange' graph does handle this scenario automatically.

How can I increase the limit of maximum allowed data points?

[Demo code (jsfiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/vynww178/)

PS: The parent library is HighStocks.

Comment: Can you share your entire code? Very hard to say what is wrong without seeing more. As you can see in this example: 50 points is not a problem: http://jsfiddle.net/sLmj0z5z/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vynww178/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply change default value of `cropThreshold` property from 50 to the value equal or higher than the number of the points in series.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.bar.cropThreshold

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/5gjb0cxa/

Comment: but this solution included the highstock methods, is there any other way to get scrollbar

Answer (score 1):

Adding to [wf4](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2394259/wf4) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46704900/5902969), For the drilldown part you can check this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34557897/5902969).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46714620/2920114 Helped me. But your answer helped me in addition to @wf4 answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like duplicate values are only being plotted once. Because you are forcing in the number of data points in the series, this is why you see blanks.

One way to have the chart display the way you want is like this: https://jsfiddle.net/wf_4/vynww178/1/

What I have done here is removed the text from each series point and added it as y-axis categories which the data will be aligned to.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'bar',
    marginLeft: 150
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Most popular ideas by April 2016'
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: 'Source: <a href="https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api">UserVoice</a>'
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    title: {
      text: null
    },
    min: 0,
    max: 4,
    scrollbar: {
      enabled: true
    },
    tickLength: 0,
    categories: ['Gantt chart',
      'Autocalculation and plotting of trend lines',
      'Allow navigator to have multiple data series',
      'Implement dynamic font size',
      'Multiple axis alignment control',
      'Stacked area (spline etc) in irregular datetime series',
      'Adapt chart height to legend height',
      'Export charts in excel sheet',
      'Toggle legend box',
      'Venn Diagram',
      'Add ability to change Rangeselector position',
      'Draggable legend box',
      'Sankey Diagram',
      'Add Navigation bar for Y-Axis in Highstock',
      'Grouped x-axis',
      'ReactJS plugin',
      '3D surface charts',
      'Draw lines over a stock chart',
      'Data module for database tables',
      'Draggable points',
      'Gantt chart',
      'Autocalculation and plotting of trend lines',
      'Allow navigator to have multiple data series',
      'Implement dynamic font size',
      'Multiple axis alignment control',
      'Stacked area (spline etc) in irregular datetime series',
      'Adapt chart height to legend height',
      'Export charts in excel sheet',
      'Toggle legend box',
      'Venn Diagram',
      'Add ability to change Rangeselector position',
      'Draggable legend box',
      'Sankey Diagram',
      'Add Navigation bar for Y-Axis in Highstock',
      'Grouped x-axis',
      'ReactJS plugin',
      '3D surface charts',
      'Draw lines over a stock chart',
      'Data module for database tables',
      'Draggable points',
      'Draggable legend box',
      'Sankey Diagram',
      'Add Navigation bar for Y-Axis in Highstock',
      'Grouped x-axis',
      'ReactJS plugin',
      '3D surface charts',
      'Draw lines over a stock chart',
      'Data module for database tables',
      'Draggable points',
      'Draggable legend box',
      'Sankey Diagram',
      'Add Navigation bar for Y-Axis in Highstock',
      'Grouped x-axis',
      'ReactJS plugin',
      '3D surface charts',
      'Draw lines over a stock chart',
      'Data module for database tables',
      'Draggable points'

    ]
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 1200,
    title: {
      text: 'Votes',
      align: 'high'
    }

  },
  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true
      }
    }
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Votes',
    data: [
      1000,
      575,
      523,
      427,
      399,
      309,
      278,
      239,
      235,
      203,
      182,
      157,
      149,
      144,
      143,
      137,
      134,
      118,
      118,
      117,
      1000,
      575,
      523,
      427,
      399,
      309,
      278,
      239,
      235,
      203,
      182,
      157,
      149,
      144,
      143,
      137,
      134,
      118,
      118,
      117,
      157,
      149,
      144,
      143,
      137,
      134,
      118,
      118,
      117,
      157,
      149,
      144,
      143,
      137,
      134,
      118,
      118,
      117
    ]
  }]
});
```

```html
<div id="container" style="height: 1000px; min-width: 320px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

Comment: I need to change the structure of data in series, as I also need to include drilldown graphs for every point. How can I do that with this?

Comment: You can still use an object in your series, its just your categories which have been set in the y-axis. e.g. `data: [{ y: 1000, url: "URLhere"},{y: 999, url: "URLhere"}]`

Comment: But in that case, I need different labels for x-axis than those defined in the categories.

Comment: It depends on how you are implementing your drilldowns, there are more than 2 different ways which I can think - however, your initial question did not mention a drilldown.

Comment: could you please share some code for the work around?