# R Highcharter: Changing xAxis Type from datetime to category

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I want to change the x-axis type from datetime to category. For example: Primary Chart would be a line chart by group and drilldown chart would be a column chart.

There is a solution given in Highcharts ([Highcharts, Can you change the chart type for drilldowns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293629/highcharts-can-you-change-the-chart-type-for-drilldowns), [Highcharts chart with 'datetime' xAxis - use categories on drilldown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27844786/highcharts-chart-with-datetime-xaxis-use-categories-on-drilldown)) but I'm not able to translate it to R.

PFB the code.

```
library("dplyr")
library("purrr")
library("highcharter")

df <- data_frame(
  car_brand = c("Hyundai","Hyundai","Hyundai", "Benz","Benz","Benz", "Tesla","Tesla","Tesla"),
  units_sold = c(10,15,20,11,8,13,6,5,7),
  date = c("2019-01-01", "2019-02-01","2019-03-01","2019-01-01","2019-02-01","2019-03-01","2019-01-01","2019-02-01","2019-03-01")
)

df$units_sold <- as.numeric(df$units_sold)
df$date <- as.Date(df$date)
df$drilldown <- paste(df$car_brand, ",", df$date)
carBrands<- df %>%
  select(date, car_brand)

getCarDetails<- function(brands){

  carList <- list()
  listofdfs <- list() #Create a list in which you intend to save your df's.

  for(i in 1:nrow(brands)){ #Loop through the numbers of ID's instead of the ID's

    #You are going to use games[i] instead of i to get the ID
    BrandCarData <- data_frame(
      car = c("H1","H2","H3","H4","H5"),
      units = c(1,2,3,4,5)
    )
    BrandCarData$units <- as.numeric(BrandCarData$units)
    dsCar <- list_parse2(BrandCarData)
    listofdfs[[i]] <- dsCar
    carList[[i]] <- list (name = brands[[2]][i],
                          type = "column",
                          id = paste(brands[[2]][i], ",", brands[[1]][i]),
                          data = listofdfs[[i]])
  }

  return(carList) #Return the list of dataframes.
}

listCar <- getCarDetails(brands = carBrands)

dfDates <- NULL
dfDates$Date <- datetime_to_timestamp(as.Date(df$date, format = "%Y-%m-%d"))
hc <- hchart(df,"line", hcaes(x=date, y =
                                units_sold, group
                              = car_brand )) %>%
  hc_xAxis(categories = dfDates$Date, title = list(text = "<b>Date</b>"), type = "datetime") %>%
  hc_plotOptions(column = list(dataLabels = list(enabled = FALSE), enableMouseTracking = TRUE))%>%
  hc_tooltip(borderWidth = 1.5,
             pointFormat = paste('<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b><br/>')) %>%
  hc_legend(enabled = TRUE) %>%
  hc_title(text = "Brand Units Sold Monthy Trend",
           style = list(fontSize = "12px", fontWeight = "bold")) %>%
  hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "<b>Units <br>(In Thousands)</br></b>"))
hc

hc1 <- hc %>%
  hc_drilldown(allowPointDrilldown = TRUE,
               series = listCar)
hc1
```

[image: Brand-wise Units Sold Monthly Trend]

[image: Units Sold for Each Car Model]

As can be seen from the attached graphs, the x-axis of second chart is still showing x-axis labels in datetime format.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on raf18seb's inputs, I have found the solution to customizing the x-Axis labels on the drilldown. In addition to that, I will also be sharing how to change title of the chart and axes.

In my earlier code, I was specifying the x-Axis type in hc_xAxis as show in the code below:

```
hc_xAxis(categories = dfDates$Date, title = list(text = "<b>Date</b>"), type = "datetime")
```

This was the main cause of the issue. You should not specify the category at primary level, instead, specify the category type at drilldown level. Please find the modified code below:

```
getCarDetails<- function(brands){
  //This function can also be used to dynamically populate the data for drilldown //chart instead of specifiying it inside a JS code.
  carList <- list()
  listofdfs <- list() 
  for(i in 1:nrow(brands)){ 
    BrandCarData <- data_frame(
      car = c("H1","H2","H3","H4","H5"),
      units = c(1,2,3,4,5)
    )
    BrandCarData$units <- as.numeric(BrandCarData$units)
    dsCar <- list_parse2(BrandCarData)
    listofdfs[[i]] <- dsCar
    carList[[i]] <- list (name = brands[[2]][i],
                          type = "column", //Specify the xAxis category type
                          id = paste(brands[[2]][i], ",", brands[[1]][i]),
                          data = listofdfs[[i]])
  }

  return(carList) #Return the list of dataframes.
}
```

Now, in the code below, I have also added the code to change the title of chart and axes on drilldown and drillup.

```
hchart(df,"line", hcaes(x=format(as.Date(date), "%b,%Y"), y =
                                 units_sold, group
                               = car_brand )
) %>%
  hc_drilldown(allowPointDrilldown = TRUE,
               series = listCar)%>%
  hc_chart(events=list(drilldown=JS('function(e) 
                                      {
                                       this.setTitle({text: "Units Distribution Across Cars"});
                                       this.yAxis[0].axisTitle.attr({ text: "Units (in Thousands)"});
                                       this.xAxis[0].axisTitle.attr({ text: "Car Types" });
                                    }'),
                       drillup = JS("function() {this.update({title: {text: 'Brand-wise Units Sold Monthy Trend' }});
                                                 this.xAxis[0].setTitle({ text: 'Date' });
            this.yAxis[0].setTitle({ text: 'Units Sold (in Thousands)' });}")
  ))%>%
  hc_xAxis(title = list(text = "<b>Date</b>")) %>%
  hc_plotOptions(column = list(dataLabels = list(enabled = FALSE), enableMouseTracking = TRUE))%>%
  hc_tooltip(borderWidth = 1.5,
             pointFormat = paste('<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b><br/>')) %>%
  hc_legend(enabled = TRUE) %>%
  hc_title(text = "Brand-wise Units Sold Monthy Trend",
           style = list(fontSize = "12px", fontWeight = "bold"))%>%
  hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "<b>Units <br>(In Thousands)</br></b>"))
```

Hope anyone who faces this issue in the future will find this useful.

Answer (score 0):

Similar question: [Drilldown to multiple series from different groups - Highcharter (in R)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57845118/drilldown-to-multiple-series-from-different-groups-highcharter-in-r/57856347#57856347)

You can also find similar Highcharts drilldown examples in R (Highcharter) here: https://stackoverflow.com/users/8618934/raf18seb?tab=answers

**edit:** I copied/pasted code from my link above and added just one line "type: 'column'". Here is a working example of drilldown from line to column:

```
library(highcharter)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df <- tibble(x = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5, 4), y = c(1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 4, 6, 5), key = c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3), rep("C", 3)),
             drilldown = c(rep("a", 3), rep("b", 3), rep("c", 3)))

drill1 <- data.frame(
  x = c(1,2,3),
  y = c(3, 3, 1)
)
drill1 <- list_parse2(drill1)

drill2 <- data.frame(
  x = c(1,2,4),
  y = c(1, 5, 1)
)
drill2 <- list_parse2(drill2)

drill3 <- data.frame(
  x = c(1,2,4),
  y = c(4, 3, 1)
)
drill3 <- list_parse2(drill3)


hchart(df, "line", 
       hcaes(x = x, y = y, group = key),
       color = c("#A63A50", "#37123C", "#DDA77B"),
       drilldown = TRUE) %>% 
  hc_chart(events = list(drilldown = JS("function(e) {
            e.preventDefault()
            var chart = this,
              series = [{
                type: 'column',
                data: [5, 5, 5, 3, 2]
              }, {
              type: 'column',
                data: [3, 3, 7, 3, 3]
              }];

            chart.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, series[0]);
            chart.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, series[1]);
            chart.applyDrilldown();
        }"))) %>% 
  hc_plotOptions(line = list(marker = list(enabled = FALSE), legendIndex = 1)) %>% 
  hc_drilldown(
    allowPointDrilldown = TRUE,
    series = list(
      list(
        id = "a",
        data = drill1
      ),
      list(
        id = "b",
        data = drill2
      ),
      list(
        id = "c",
        data = drill3
      )
    )
  )
```

**edit 2:**

Here is a code that will allow you to change the xAxis' type to category after drilldown:

```
hc_chart(events = list(drilldown = JS("function(){
    this.xAxis[0].update({
      categories: ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
    });
  }"))) %>%
```

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.drilldown
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#update
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.categories

Comment: My question was related to creating a different chart in drilldown as mentioned in the given example in the question.

Comment: And my answer was exactly about that. My answer showed you how you can use custom JavaScript code in R (JS() method), and how you can use chart.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown() method to add in drilldown whatever series you like. For example you have a line chart and you add column series as drilldown. Please, get more familiar with that link.

Comment: If you are not an advanced programmer and you don't know R and JavaScript, then show me what you've already got and ask a more specific question - I will help you with that.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I will try them out. Also, I have added more details to my question.

Comment: You added your code which doesn't work. I can see you are trying to run 2 charts hc and hc1 - drilldown in Highcharts doesn't work like that. I don't want to be rude, don't get me wrong, but you have a working example in the link above. Instead of checking and understanding it, you provided your code and you are waiting for someone else solve your issue. It's not nice. I also edited my answer - you will find there code from the link I provided.

Comment: Apologies for that, I have now fixed the code.I wanted to clarify few concers that you've raised below:

1. "hc" and "hc1" are variables in R. They have no relation with Highcharts. I've created two separate variable for my convenience. So, that any error in drilldown doesn't cause issues with the first highchart that I've created. 

2. I also don't want to be rude. But it would have been better if you have actually tried to read my question. I have written that code specifically based on your previous comment to add more details and make the question more specific.

Comment: Also, I have read your code. It tells about creating another chart in drilldown. But not about changing the xAxis type from datetime to category. I have facing issues with formatting the second chart in the drilldown.

Kindly read the question carefully before making such comments.

Thank You.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205740/discussion-between-mayank-lal-and-raf18seb).

Comment: Well, if you have another question, do not edit your first one, because you are making a mess. After you asked the first question and you got the answer, create a new thread with a new question or ask your question **below**. How other people (and me) will know what this thread is about when you change it over and over? I edited my answer (properly) so you can see how to change the xAxis type after drilldown.

Comment: Well, I didn't get the answer at that time and based on the comments, I made the question more specific and detailed. IMHO, that's not making a mess. Thanks for the help. 

Also, if you have downvoted the question, kindly reverse it if it matches your standards. TIA.

Comment: Your primary question was **"how to change series type in drilldowned series"**. I answered your question. Then you changed it... Everything is in the history.

Comment: I will reverse my downvote with pleasure if you edit your question and reverse your first one.

Comment: At Jan 9, 16:09, you asked me to share more details and make the question more specific. Next day at Jan 10, 6:52, when I saw your reply, I made the required changes. Kindly point out where I've done the mistake. 

I did what you asked me to do. Is that my mistake? 

If yes, then keep your downvote. I can live with that.